# Improving performance: How can I archive Grails Domain Class

Tags: mysql, grails

I am running a blog site built on top of grails. Over the time the mysql database is growing.
The database has a table name 'post'. This table contains almost 1 million entries. Querying this table is becoming very time consuming.

Now I am trying to split the table and want to archive old entries. So that complicated database queries take less time.

What I am trying to accomplish is something like this,

```
class Post{
    //... properties
}

class PostArchive extends Post{

}
```

Will this approach increase performance? Is there any plugin available for accomplish these type of task?

Comment: It's difficult to say if this will increase performance without seeing what is not performing well. E.g. your question doesn't include the queries you are trying to optimize. I think unless you provide that information this isn't going to get a good answer.

Comment: Any SELECT query on the post table is taking much longer time to execute.
Join query with User table making the situation even worst.

Comment: Have you optimized your database with indexes and such? I'd consider starting there before changing the application. The reason why I ask is because I have Grails apps with hundreds of millions of records and often select (with multiple joins) from those tables and see sub second responses.

Comment: I haven't used any indexing yet. Thank you for mentioning about it.  Wolud you please share your experience about the implementation. Should I use  GORM for indexing column or index the colums directly in db.

Comment: It's really up to you. Either one will result in the same thing. Often it's easier to model complex indexes in the database instead of GORM but that's just my personal experience (and lack of experience using GORM to manage the indexes). I'm sure it's fully capable if you put the effort in to learn how.

Answer (score 0):

We create an abstract domain with our core setup and then extend from that. So you would have

```
abstract class BasePost {

class Post extends BasePost{

class PostArchive extends BasePost{
```